# Reference to Type 'Route' claims it is defined in 'System.web'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a area to my application but it throws the below error at

context.MapRoute

I have system.web and system.web.mvc dlls referred in my application. What may be the issue?

My application is targeting .Net core 2.0

Any pointers please?

[image: error info]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting your projecto to .Net core 2.0 and it's a ASP.NET Core, than you should follow [these instructions on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas). You don't need those references to System.Web.

You can do area registration with MapRoute in your startup class for example, and the folder/file structure  will do the rest:

```cs
...
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "areaRoute",
         template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "default",
         template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
```