# Route claim it is defined in system.web but it not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-framework-version

when i migrate from .netframework to .net core than I get this error in .netcore 3.1 i follow this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847326/reference-to-type-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-web-but-it-could-not-be-f)   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417383/reference-to-type-route-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-web/49421678) but still not able to resolve this issue .

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Web API configuration and services
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );

            // Configure formatting settings
            ConfigureFormatting(config);

            // Add Global Exception Handling and Logging
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), GlobalExceptionHandler.GetInstance());
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger());
        }
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Route' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found   WorkerRole

is their alternet so on change it remove my error it work similar .

any suggestion is accepted.

Comment: Those look like ASP.NET WebAPI types, not ASP.NET Core types...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a config file in the .NET framework, To achieve this in .NET core 3.1 you should add your configuration in a startup.cs file for .net core.

e.g In configure method of startup.cs file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```